# Running rspec in Sinatra app just starts the server

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I'm using rspec to test my Sinatra app. The app is super simple, and so are the tests, but when I run rspec from the CLI, it just starts the app server. I've never had this happen.

Here's what my `spec_helper.rb` looks like:

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb
require File.expand_path '../../app.rb', __FILE__

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = "test"

require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

set :environment, :test
set :run, false
set :raise_errors, true
set :logging, false

module RSpecMixin
  def app
    App.new
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color_enabled = true
  config.tty = true
  config.formatter = :documentation
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
  config.include RSpecMixin
end
```

And my spec is just

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "My Sinatra Application" do
  it "should allow accessing the home page" do
    expect(1).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

I can't get rspec to run.

### What I've tried:

I've tried the recommendations in this [Sinatra testing guide](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html). Also the rspec Sinatra [test recipe](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/testing/rspec). In [this blog post](http://blog.codenursery.com/2011/11/adding-rspec-to-sinatra.html), the `set :run, false` looked promising, but no dice. Then I thought, I'll just [define a rake task](https://github.com/daddz/sinatra-rspec-bundler-template). Putting the `rspec` gem in the `test` group and setting the `RACK_ENV` to test. All these things just start the app server:

```
$ rake spec
[2014-03-08 22:06:38] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-03-08 22:06:38] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
== Sinatra/1.4.4 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-03-08 22:06:38] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=21538 port=4567
```

Halp?

Comment: What does your `app.rb` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It's embarrassing, but I was switching back and forth between the [modular and classic style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra%3a%3aBase%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) deciding which I liked best, and I had left an errant `App.run!` call at the bottom of my `app.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `new()` from your `def app`:

```
module RSpecMixin
  def app
    App
  end
end
```

Comment: This still starts the server. What other information can I provide to help diagnose?

Answer (score 1):

An other way to create your app for testing is something like this:

```
APP = Rack::Builder.parse_file('config.ru').first

module RSpecMixin
  def app
    APP
  end
end
```

Obvious this works only if you use config.ru.